# New column based on conditions with different dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data sets

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"skuid" :["A","B","C","D","E"], "price": [0,0,0,0,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"skuid" :["A","B","C","D"],"salesprice" :[10,0,np.nan,30],"regularprice" : [9,10,0,2]})
```

I want to insert sales price and regular price in price with conditions:
If df1 skuid and df2 skuid matches and df2 salesprice is not zero, use salesprice as price value. if sku's match and df2 salesprice is zero, use regularprice. if not use zero as price value.

```
def pric(df1,df2):
    if (df1['skuid'] == df2['skuid'] and salesprice !=0): 
        price = salesprice 
    elif (df1['skuid'] == df2['skuid'] and regularprice !=0):
        price = regularprice
    else:
        price = 0
```

I made a function with similar conditions but its not working. the result should look like in df1

```
skuid  price
  A      10
  B      10
  C      0
  D      30
  E      0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`, but first use `.loc` to change salesprice values to regularprice values where equal to zero. Filnally use `.fillna(0) to satisfy remaining condition:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"skuid" :["A","B","C","D","E"], "price": [0,0,0,0,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"skuid" :["A","B","C","D"],"salesprice" :[10,0,np.nan,30],"regularprice" : [9,10,0,2]})
df = df2.copy()
df.loc[df['salesprice'] == 0, 'salesprice'] = df['regularprice']
df = pd.merge(df1[['skuid']],
              df[['skuid','salesprice']].rename({'salesprice':'price'}, axis=1),
              how='left', on='skuid').fillna(0)
df
Out[1]: 
  skuid  price
0     A   10.0
1     B   10.0
2     C    0.0
3     D   30.0
4     E    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.merge` and `np.select`:

```
In [1228]: import numpy as np

In [1229]: res = df1.merge(df2, on='skuid', how='outer')

In [1230]: conditions = [(res.salesprice.notna() & res.regularprice.notna()) & res.salesprice.ne(0), (res.salesprice.notna() & res.regularprice.notna()) & res.salesprice.eq(0)]    
In [1233]: choices = [res.salesprice, res.regularprice]

In [1235]: res['price'] = np.select(conditions, choices) 
In [1238]: res.drop(['salesprice', 'regularprice'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [1239]: res
Out[1239]: 
  skuid  price
0     A   10.0
1     B   10.0
2     C    0.0
3     D   30.0
4     E    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your answers, Meanwhile I also came up with a method,

I used `merge` and `fillna`

which is

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on = 'skuid', right_on = 'skuid')
df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(['SalesPrice'])
df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(['RegularPrice'])
df['price'] = df['price'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Kindly accept what you think the best solution is as and/or upvote if helpful. Thank you!